# Question about InputAutoReplacements

Tags: formatting

I have a question about `InputAutoReplacements`.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
    InputAutoReplacements -> {"spa" -> 
            RowBox[{"〚", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "〛"}] } ]
```

It works, but  always adds in spacing automatically.  How can I get it fixed? Thanks!

[image]

Xiang Li

Comment: Hi @Xiang Li, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I added the image according to the link in your post. Also please have a look at [*how to format your post with markdown*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code). Proper formatting will make your post more readable and attract more attention. Have a good time on this site!

Comment: The trigger of this InputAutoReplacement is Space Key, otherwise how to type the word space?  You can also try ESC Key or other None-DigitCharacter key when finish typing 'spa'

Comment: @HyperGroups Could you post an answer? :)

Comment: I do a fast space+backspace, but I'd be happy to get an alternative one-key-only solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my little answer since Kuba recommend me post my comment as an answer.

The trigger of this InputAutoReplacement is <kbd>Space</kbd> Key, otherwise how can you type the word "space"?

You can also try <kbd>ESC</kbd> Key or other None-DigitCharacter keys when finishing typing "spa".

Comment: Hi,@HyperGroups! Thanks a lot!